# Extracting and Exporting multiple band values after appllying reduce regions to a image collection

Tags: google-earth-engine, export, modis, reduceregion

I am trying to extract 'Optical_Depth_055','AOD_Uncertainty','AOD_QA' bands from Modis data at point locations (point collection)
I was able to export just Optical_Depth_055 data using reduceRegions and using selectors = ['date','mean'] to export.
But when i added the other two bands i wasnt able to change the selectors for export, and keep getting empty export.
Here is the code:

```
var pointList = [
  ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point( 72.922099, 19.1653323 )).set("id", "1"),
 // ee.Feature(ee.Geometry.Point( 72.813993, 19.000083 )).set("id", "2")
  
];

var pointCollection = ee.FeatureCollection(pointList);

Map.centerObject(pointCollection); // Center map on sample points

var startDate = '2023-12-01';
var endDate = '2023-12-31';

var AOD = MODIS.filter(ee.Filter.date(startDate,endDate)).select(['Optical_Depth_055','AOD_Uncertainty','AOD_QA']);

var calculateMeanAOD = function(image) {
  return image.reduceRegions({
    collection: pointCollection,
    reducer: ee.Reducer.mean(),
    scale:  1000, // Adjust the scale as needed
    //crs: 'EPSG:4326'
  }).map(function(feature) {
    return feature.set('date', image.date());
  });
};

// Calculate the mean AOD for each polygon for each day
var AODMeanPerDay = AOD.map(calculateMeanAOD);

print(AODMeanPerDay.limit(4));
var AODMeanPerDay2 = AODMeanPerDay.flatten();
print(AODMeanPerDay2.first())

//Export the data to Google Drive
Export.table.toDrive({
  collection: AODMeanPerDay2,//.filter(ee.Filter.notNull(["mean"])),
  description: 'AOD_Mean_Per_Day',
  selectors: ['date', 'Optical_Depth_055','AOD_Uncertainty','AOD_QA'] // Specify the properties you want to export
});
```

Outputs:
[image: Output]

[image: Outpu]